# Inferring Eq typeclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm writing a CRUD like application and have a lot of lookups by primary key(primary keys can have different types). So I defined following typeclass:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Eq b => HasPK a b where
  getPK :: a -> b
```

Now I can write:

```
import Data.Maybe

lookupPK :: HasPK a b => b -> [a] -> Maybe a
lookupPK s = listToMaybe . filter ((== s) . getPK)
```

Now, when I want to compare two things with PK, I just want to compare their PK's. So, I'm trying to define this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

instance (HasPK a b) => Eq a where
  (==) = (==) `on` getPK
```

But now it gives me:

```
src/Utils.hs:61:10: Could not deduce (HasPK a b0) …
      arising from the ambiguity check for an instance declaration
    from the context (HasPK a b)
      bound by an instance declaration: HasPK a b => Eq a
      at /home/utdemir/workspace/.../Utils.hs:61:10-28
    The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
    In the ambiguity check for: forall a b. HasPK a b => Eq a
    To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
    In the instance declaration for ‘Eq a’
Compilation failed.
```

Can anyone explain this error to me? Am I on the right track, or is there a safer way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a functional dependency here: use

```
class Eq b => HasPK a b | a -> b where
  getPK :: a -> b
```

and enable whatever extension GHC points to.

The issue lies in the possibility of having multiple PKs for the same type,
as in

```
instance HasPK MyType Int where ...
instance HasPK MyType String where ...
```

Since the above double instance could be added later, code like `` (==) `on` getPK `` is potentially ambiguous. Indeed, when the instances above are added, it does not specify whether to use the `Int` PK or the `String` one.

---

However, an instance like

```
instance (HasPK a b) => Eq a where
  ...
```

is likely to cause problems, since it overlaps with any other `Eq` instance. Be careful here. I would instead write

```
equalPK :: HasPK a b => a -> a -> Bool
equalPK = (==) `on` getPK
```

and then provide explicit instances to all the relevant types as this:

```
instance Eq MyType1 where (==) = equalPK
instance Eq MyType2 where (==) = equalPK
...
```

---

As another alternative, you can use a type family such as

```
class HasPK a where
   type PK a
   getPK :: a -> PK a

equalPK :: Eq (PK a) => a -> a -> Bool
equalPK = (==) `on` getPK

instance Eq MyType1 where (==) = equalPK
...
```

Comment: Yes, after defining that instance, I got `src/Utils.hs:52:20: Overlapping instances for Eq Integer arising from a use of ‘/=’ …
    Matching instances:
      instance Eq Integer -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp:GHC.Integer.Type’
      instance (Eq b, HasPK a b) => Eq a`. But I wasn't expecting that error since `Integer` hasn't got an `HasPk Integer b` instance. I'd understand the error if I define both Eq and HasPK, but since there isn't `HasPK Integer`, shouldn't it directly use ordinary `Eq` instance?

Comment: @utdemir The problem is: an `instance C a => Eq a` applies to every type, even to those for which `C a` is false (!). Haskell will commit to use this instance, and when `C a` it false it will error out, instead of backtracking and look for other instances. This is done because with backtracking the problem becomes much harder, and the Haskell designers were concerned with compilation time. GHC has an `OverlappingInstances` extension that relaxes this restriction, but I'd not recommend it. Overlapping instances are best to be avoided, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you, I went with type family solution since it looks like the least controversial extension is that one.